# Javascript: Meaning?

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
    'use strict';
```

What does this mean?

```
var antwoord = function (tekst) {
    var berichtvenster = document.getElementById('berichtvenster');
    berichtvenster.innerHTML += "<p>" + tekst + "</p>\n";
```

And what is the code above doing? Step by step? 
I think it makes a function (antwoord) and var berichtvenster takes the (berichtvenster ID) from HTML? `berichtvenster.innerHTML` prints out tekst on different textline? Am i right?

Comment: I'm not going to copy info here, but please referrer to MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: Contents of the variable `tekst` are added inside a `<p>` to the existing contents of the element whose id is `berichtvenster`.

Comment: The 'Use Strict' keyword has also been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851/what-does-use-strict-do-in-javascript-and-what-is-the-reasoning-behind-it

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function () {
```

This line initiates an anonymous function and appends it to the `window.onload` event, i.e. the code within the function will be executed at when the page and all its resources are loaded in the DOM.

```
'use strict';
```

This line says that the proceeding code is to be executed in *strict* mode, which means that a handful of common pitfalls and dubious codes will be treated as errors. [See more on strict mode here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

```
var antwoord = function(tekst) {
```

This line initiates a function named `antwoord` (not really: see comments) that accepts one parameter (`tekst`).

```
var berichtvenster = document.getElementById('berichtvenster');
```

This line looks for an element of the ID "berichtvenster", and assigns a reference to that element, if any is found, to the newly created variable of the same name.

```
berichtvenster.innerHTML += "<p>" + tekst + "</p>\n";
```

This line assumes that such an element was indeed found, and proceeds to update its `innerHTML` property, i.e. to change the HTML content of the element. It changes the content to be a paragraph containing only the text that was passed to the `antwoord` function.

Comment: the function is not named antwoord, its an anoymous function assigned to a variable...

Comment: Oops. That is of course correct.